# should I use a bit set or a vector? C++

Tags: c++, vector, bitset

I need to be able to store an array of binary numbers in c++ which will be passed through different methods and eventually outputted to file and terminal,

What are the key differences between vectors and bit sets and which would be easiest and/or more efficient to use?

(I do not know how many bits I need to store)

Comment: You may overthink your problem ([XY](http://xyproblem.info/)?). Hint: All numbers inside the computer are binary ;)

Comment: bitsets are of a compile-time determined size, anyway.

Comment: You also mention an `array` - do you have a fixed size collection of numbers? What do you want to do with them?

Comment: All depends on what you want to do with those binary numbers. Can you give us an idea on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you planning on storing bits (or bools) in say a vector? If so, take a look at this: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool. Otherwise just store the numbers, and count the bits in each or whatever it is you are needing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to do binary.

You could also use [boost.dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) which is like `std::bitset` but not with fixed bits.
The main drawback is dependency on boost if you don't already use it.

You could also store your input in `std::vector<char>` and use a bitset per `char` to convert binary notation.

As others already told: `std::bitset` uses a fixed number of bits.

`std::vector<bool>` is not always advised because it has its quirks, as it is not a real container ([gotw](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill09.htm)).

Answer (score 2):

**`std::bitset` size should be known at compile time**, so your choice is obvious - use `std::vector<bool>`.
Since it's implemented not the same as `std::vector<char>` (since a single element takes a bit, not a full char), it should be a good solution in terms of memory use.

Comment: Take note of the specialization that makes this efficient, and read the docs. It does break some other assumptions about how a vector should behave.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many bits you need to store at compilation time, you cannot use bitset, as it's size is fixed. Because of this, you should you `vector<bool>`, as it can be resized dynamically. If you want an array of bits saved like this, you can then use `vector< vector<bool> >`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case you should use `std::vector` with the value type of `std::bitset`. Using such an approach you can consider your "binary numbers" either like strings or like objects of some integer type and at the same time it is easy to do binary operations like setting or resetting bits.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, as he doesn't know how many bits he will need to store.

Comment: @HonzaDejdar All integer types have fixed number of bits. So there is no problem.:)

Comment: If he doesn't need store bigger numbers, than sure. I thought from the OP that he doesn't know at all how many bits he'll need to store.

Comment: @HonzaDejdar I think it is the author of the question who will decide what to use, will not he? My task is to suggest an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any specific upper bound for the size of the numbers you need to store, then you need to store your data in two different dimensions:

- The first dimension will be the number, whose size varies.
- The second dimension will be your array of numbers.

For the latter, using `std:vector` is fine if you require your values to be contiguous in memory. For the numbers themselves you don't need any data structure at all: just allocate memory using `new` and an unsigned primitive type such as `unsigned char`, `uint8_t` or any other if you have alignment constraints.

If, on the other hand, you know that your numbers won't be larger than let's say 64 bits, then use a data type that you know will hold this amount of data such as `uint64_t`.

PS: remember that what you store are numbers. The computer will store them in binary whether you use them as such or with any other representation.